# My program doesn't print out Strings converted to ints

Tags: java, sorting

I have a simple program that asks you to enter numbers by keyboard (each number being separated by a space or by a comma) and then sorts them from lower to higher and prints them.

The problem is that the numbers aren't printed out.

Here is the source code:

```
public class StartHere {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Type random numbers: ");
    String input = new String(scanner.nextLine());
    scanner.close();
    String[] numString = new String[input.length()];

    int a = 0;
    int i = 0;
    for (; i < input.length() - 1;) {
        if (Character.isDigit(input.charAt(a))) { // If the character at input[a] is a digit
            numString[i] += Character.toString(input.charAt(a)); // it is added to numString[i]
            if(!(a+1 > input.length())){
                a++;
            }
        }
        if (numString[i] != null && !Character.isDigit(input.charAt(a))) { // If numString[i] is already in use and the char at input[a] is not a digit
            if(!(i+1 > input.length())){
                i++;
            }
            if(!(a+1 > input.length())){
                a++;
            }
        }
        if (numString[i] == null && !Character.isDigit(input.charAt(a))){ // If numString[i] is not in used and the character at char[a] is not a digit.
             if(!(a+1 > input.length())){
                a++;
             }
        }
    }
    a = 0;
    i = 0;
    int[] numbers = new int[numString.length];
    for(; i < numString.length - 1; i++){
        numbers[i] = Integer.parseInt(numString[i]);
    }
    quicksort(numbers, 0, numbers.length - 1);
    for(i = 0; i < numbers.length - 1; i++){
        if(i != numbers.length){
            System.out.print(numbers[i] + ", ");
        }else{
            System.out.println(numbers[i] + ".");
        }
    }
}

public static void quicksort(int numbers[], int left, int right) {

      int pivot = numbers[left]; // takes the first element as pivot
      int l = left; // l searches from left to right
      int r = right; // r searches from right to left
      int aux;

      while(l<r){ // While searches doesn't cross
         while((numbers[l] <= pivot) && (l < r)) l++; // searches for an element higher than the pivot
         while(numbers[r] > pivot) r--;         // Searches for an element smaller than the pivot
         if (l<r) {                      // if searches haven't been crossed                   
             aux = numbers[l];           // they are exchanged
             numbers[l] = numbers[r];
             numbers[r] = aux;
         }
       }
       numbers[left] = numbers[r]; // The pivot is placed in a way that we have the 
       numbers[r] = pivot;         // smaller digits at the left and the higher digits at the right
       if(left < r-1)
          quicksort(numbers, left, r-1); // left subarray is sorted
       if(r+1 < right)
          quicksort(numbers, r+1, left); // right subarray is sorted
    }
}
```

**EDITED:** Added an `a++;`expression in the 26th line that prevents the program from entering into an infinite loop and a new `if` block that prevents the program from "freezing", but now I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 16
at java.lang.String.charAt(Unknown Source)
at StartHere.main(StartHere.java:21)
```

Being this the input:

```
Type random numbers: 246, 421, 123, 2
```

Comment: Example input, and actual and expected output for it? Looks like you are getting an exception?

Comment: My compiler acts like if everything were okay, so I don't think that I'm getting an exception.

Comment: You program hangs in the first loop. You could use `String[] numString = input.split(",");` instead of loop and try.

Comment: But why is that? The reason why I wanted to do it with the loop is that in that way I don't have to specify what caracter has to be inserted after each number.

Comment: when you encounter a first non digit character, you program will hang as it wont enter any of the condition block. I think the second condition in first for loop should be `numString[i] != null && !Character.isDigit(input.charAt(a))`

Comment: You have two more problems in first for loop.

1. you condition should be `a < input.length()` and not `i < input.length()`.
2. when you encounter a non digit character , you need to increment a as well. so you need to move `a++` outside of both the ifs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm answering by providing an alternative that works:

```
System.out.println( Arrays.stream(input.split("\\D+"))
  .map(Integer::parseInt)
  .sorted()
  .map(String::valueOf)
  .collect(Collectors.joining(", ", "", ".")));
```

And it's only 1 line.

---

By popular demand, here's how it works:

- `input.split("\\D+")` returns `String[]` of numbers, which are separated by *non* numbers - `\D` means "non digit" and `\D+` means one or more non-digits
- `Arrays.stream()` creates a stream from an array
- `map(Integer::parseInt)` turns each `String` from the split into an `Integer`. This is needed so the next step will sort in *numerical* order, not *lexographical* order - n.b. `10 > 2` but `"10" < "2"`
- `sorted()` sorts the stream of Integers (in *numerical* order)
- `map(String::valueOf)` turn the `Integers` back into `Strings`, ready for the next step
- `collect()` combines the stream to a single object. See next point for how...
- `Collectors.joining(", ", "", ".")` is a pre-canned collector that produces a single String from the stream, joining them with parameter 1 as the separator, prefix of the parameter 2 and suffix of parameter 3

Comment: what if he is not using Java8 ?

Comment: @DeendayalGarg Java 8 has been around for 2 years now. If he's not using it he really should set about starting to.

Comment: I agree. But we should not assume. Instead of making him to upgrade to Java 8  we should suggest the problems with his code.

Comment: Please provide an explanation of the supplied code. Not everyone is familiar with these newer Java 8 sequence operators, so this answer would be made a lot more useful if it discussed the supplied code.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo it's been a very long time since 2-year old technology was considered "new" in the IT world. This code is now mainstream. By now, there are countless blogs and tutorials that cover basic usage of the Java 8 stream API; I wouldn't be adding much value repeating a précis of those here.

Comment: I've got Java 8, but I understand nothing of your code.
Thats a good thing, anyways. I'm going to look it up on google tomorrow. I ran out of coffee.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo I have added an explanation

Comment: @Ferrybig fyi, I added an explanation

Comment: @JavaNoob fyi, I added an explanation

Comment: Sorry for answering late.
I tried with your code but I have an exception with the `.collect()` method.
This is what it says: `The method collect(Collector<? super Integer,A,R>) in the type Stream<Integer> is not applicable for the arguments (Collector<CharSequence,capture#1-of ?,String>)`
I already solved my problem but it would be great if I can do the same thing with your code.

Comment: @javanoob oops, joining only works with Strings. I added a mapping step to create strings from the integers. See edited answer

Answer (score 1):

when your program reads the first "," ,

It will increment the "i", but "a" is not incremented so,

input.charAt(a) will be ',' and numString[i] is null

so both the if condition will be skipped and it cause an **infinite** loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Your Input String Is Like Type random numbers: 12,654,123,3 
//you first need to split this string with (,) because 
//scanner object read the line as string object so you need to fist split this input string with (,). then you can perform sort operation in easy way.

String[] splitStr = input.split(",");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is code example, the number will print out. 
I modified your code `modified here`. I hope it will help you.

**Edited:**

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Type random numbers: ");
    String input = new String(scanner.nextLine());
    scanner.close();

    // modified here -> split whitespace, a literal comma
    String[] numString = input.split("\\s*,\\s*");

    int i = 0;
    int[] numbers = new int[numString.length];
    for (; i < numString.length; i++) {
        // modified here -> make sure numString[] isn't null and empty string
        if (numString[i] != null && !"".equals(numString[i])) {
            numbers[i] = Integer.parseInt(numString[i]);
        }
    }
    quicksort(numbers, 0, numbers.length - 1);
    // modified here
    for (i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {

        if (i < (numbers.length - 1)) {
            System.out.print(numbers[i] + ", ");
        } else {
            System.out.println(numbers[i] + ".");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is what i get with your code:

First line: Type random numbers: 24,62,1

Second line: 6, 2, 2, 1, 4.

Being the first line the `System.out.print()` expression and the input, and the second line the output.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. It simply do this work. You can seperate your inputs either from comma or space. BUT not by them both.

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Type random numbers: ");
    String input = new String(scanner.nextLine());
    scanner.close();
    String arr[];

    boolean isComma = false;

    //check for comma
    if (input.indexOf(",") != -1) {
        isComma = true;
    }

    //split based on comma or space
    if (isComma) {
        arr = input.split(",");
    } else {
        arr = input.split(" ");
    }

    int series[] = new int[arr.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        series[i] = Integer.parseInt(arr[i].trim());
    }

    Arrays.sort(series);

    for (int i = 0; i < series.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(series[i] + " ");
    }

    System.out.println("");
```

Comment: I'm going to try this tomorrow, I ran out of coffee!